# Text-Based Pokemon Battling Simulator

Tags: c++, game

How can I improve the visual appeal Of My text-based Pokemon battling simulator?

I created a Pokemon battling simulator in C++. I showed it to my mom, dad, and brother, and they didn't say anything about this, but I have a tugging feeling that they didn't think it looked to great. I myself don't think it looks to great. I'm not talking about the code (the code is a huge mess), I'm talking about the actual terminal application. And not only do I want to make it look better, I also want to help make it easier for the user to give his inputs.

There are a bunch of files, but many of them aren't that important, so here is the github page: https://github.com/nishantc1527/Pokemon-Simulator. But if you only want the important files (it might look like a lot, but you only pretty much need to look at main.cpp and pokemon.hpp):

If you want to quickly run this, I added a button so you can run it on repl.it. It's at the top of the gitub README page

In a file called  `main.cpp` (the main class)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "helper_functions.hpp"
#include "gameplay_functions.hpp"
#include "helper_constants.hpp"

int main() {
    read_file();
    try {
        start();
    } catch(std::exception e) {
        print("Quitting");
    }
}

void start() {
    while (true) {
        switch (get_input("Do You Want To Create A Team Or Battle Using Existing Teams?", false, {
            "Create Team",
            "Battle"
            })) {
        case CREATE_TEAM:
            create_team();
            break;
        case BATTLE:
            battle();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void create_team() {
    std::vector<std::string> u_team;
    while (u_team.size() < 6) {
        switch (get_input("Do You Want To Create A New Pokemon Or Add An Existing Pokemon To Your Team?", false, {
            "Create Pokemon",
            "Add Pokemon"
            })) {
        case CREATE_POKEMON:
            create_pokemon();
            break;
        case ADD_POKEMON:
            add_pokemon(u_team);
            break;
        }
    }

    print("What Do You Want To Name Your Team?");
    std::string team_name;
    std::getline(std::cin, team_name);
    add_team_to_file(team_name, u_team);
    u_teams[team_name] = u_team;
}

void battle() {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>> key_value = key_value_pairs(u_teams);
    std::vector<std::string> keys;

    for (auto& pair : key_value) {
        keys.push_back(pair.first);
    }

    int in = get_input("Player 1: Which Team Do You Want To Use?", false, keys);
    if (in == -1) {
        print("You Have No Teams To Battle With.");
        return;
    }
    std::string& p1_team_name = keys[in - 1];

    in = get_input("Player 2: Which Team Do You Want To Use?", false, keys);
    std::string& p2_team_name = keys[in - 1];

    std::vector<pokemon> p1_team;
    std::vector<std::string>& p1_team_pokemon = u_teams[p1_team_name];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        p1_team.push_back(pokemon(u_pokemon[p1_team_pokemon[i]][0], p1_team_pokemon[i],
            u_pokemon[p1_team_pokemon[i]][1],
            u_pokemon[p1_team_pokemon[i]][2],
            u_pokemon[p1_team_pokemon[i]][3],
            u_pokemon[p1_team_pokemon[i]][4]));
    }

    std::vector<pokemon> p2_team;
    std::vector<std::string> p2_team_pokemon = u_teams[p2_team_name];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        p2_team.push_back(pokemon(u_pokemon[p2_team_pokemon[i]][0], p2_team_pokemon[i],
            u_pokemon[p2_team_pokemon[i]][1],
            u_pokemon[p2_team_pokemon[i]][2],
            u_pokemon[p2_team_pokemon[i]][3],
            u_pokemon[p2_team_pokemon[i]][4]));
    }

    in = get_input("Player 1: Choose Your Lead", false, to_string_array(p1_team));
    pokemon& p1_lead = p1_team[in - 1];

    in = get_input("Player 2: Choose Your Lead", false, to_string_array(p2_team));
    pokemon& p2_lead = p2_team[in - 1];

    battle(p1_team, p2_team, p1_lead, p2_lead);
}

void create_pokemon() {
    std::string input_pokemon;
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> key_value = key_value_pairs(available_pokemon);
    for (auto& pair : key_value) {
        values.push_back(pair.second);
    }
    int in = get_input("Which Pokemon Do You Want To Add?", true, values);
    add_user_pokemon(available_pokemon[in]);
}

void add_pokemon(std::vector<std::string>& u_team) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>> key_value = key_value_pairs(u_pokemon);
    std::vector<std::string> keys;

    for (auto& pair : key_value) {
        keys.push_back(pair.first);
    }

    if (keys.size() == 0) {
        print("You Have No Pokemon");
        return;
    }

    int in = get_input("Which Pokemon Do You Want To Add?", true, keys);
    u_team.push_back(keys[in - 1]);
}

void battle(std::vector<pokemon>& p1_team, std::vector<pokemon>& p2_team, pokemon& p1_lead, pokemon& p2_lead) {
    pokemon& curr_p1 = p1_lead;
    pokemon& curr_p2 = p2_lead;

    while (true) {
        std::ifstream file1(curr_p1.name + ".txt");
        std::ifstream file2(curr_p2.name + ".txt");

        std::string next_line;

        while(std::getline(file1, next_line)) {
            print("                                   " + next_line);
        }

        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

        while(std::getline(file2, next_line)) {
            print(next_line);
        }

        switch (get_input("Player 1: Do You Want To Attack Or Swtich?", false,
            {
                "Attack",
                "Switch"
            }
        )) {
        case ATTACK:
            switch (get_input("Player 2: Do You Want To Attack Or Swtich?", false,
                {
                    "Attack",
                    "Switch"
                }
            )) {
            case ATTACK:
            {
                std::string p1_move = choose_move(curr_p1, 1);
                std::string p2_move = choose_move(curr_p2, 2);

                if (curr_p1.s_speed > curr_p2.s_speed) {
                    if (curr_p1.attack(p1_move, curr_p2, 2)) {
                        remove(p2_team, curr_p2);
                        int in = get_input(curr_p2.name + " Has Fainted. Player 2: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(p2_team));
                        if (in == -1) {
                            print("Player 1 Has Won!");
                            return;
                        }
                        curr_p2 = p2_team[in - 1];
                    }
                    else {
                        if (curr_p2.attack(p2_move, curr_p1, 1)) {
                            remove(p1_team, curr_p1);
                            int in = get_input(curr_p1.name + " Has Fainted. Player 1: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(p1_team));
                            if (in == -1) {
                                print("Player 2 Has Won!");
                                return;
                            }
                            curr_p1 = p1_team[in - 1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (curr_p2.attack(p2_move, curr_p1, 1)) {
                        remove(p1_team, curr_p1);
                        int in = get_input(curr_p1.name + " Has Fainted. Player 1: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(p1_team));
                        if (in == -1) {
                            print("Player 2 Has Won!");
                            return;
                        }
                        curr_p1 = p1_team[in - 1];
                    }
                    else {
                        if (curr_p1.attack(p1_move, curr_p2, 2)) {
                            remove(p2_team, curr_p2);
                            int in = get_input(curr_p2.nick + " Has Fainted. Player 2: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(p2_team));
                            if (in == -1) {
                                print("Player 1 Has Won!");
                                return;
                            }
                            curr_p2 = p2_team[in - 1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                break;

            case SWITCH:
                std::vector<pokemon> removed = temp_remove(p2_team, curr_p2);
                int in = get_input("Player 2: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(removed));
                curr_p2 = p2_team[in - 1];

                std::string p1_move = choose_move(curr_p1, 1);

                if (curr_p1.attack(p1_move, curr_p2, 2)) {
                    remove(p2_team, curr_p2);
                    int in = get_input(curr_p2.nick + " Has Fainted. Player 2: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(p2_team));
                    if (in == -1) {
                        print("Player 1 Has Won!");
                        return;
                    }
                    curr_p2 = p1_team[in - 1];
                }
            }

            break;
        case SWITCH:
            switch (get_input("Player 2: Do You Want To Attack Or Swtich?", false,
                {
                    "Attack",
                    "Switch"
                }
            )) {
            case ATTACK:
            {
                std::vector<pokemon> removed = temp_remove(p1_team, curr_p1);
                int in = get_input("Player 1: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(removed));
                curr_p1 = p1_team[in - 1];

                std::string p2_move = choose_move(curr_p2, 2);

                if (curr_p2.attack(p2_move, curr_p1, 1)) {
                    remove(p1_team, curr_p1);
                    int in = get_input(curr_p1.name + " Has Fainted. Player 1: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(p1_team));
                    if (in == -1) {
                        print("Player 2 Has Won!");
                        return;
                    }
                    curr_p1 = p1_team[in - 1];
                }
            }

                break;
            case SWITCH:
                std::vector<pokemon> removed = temp_remove(p1_team, curr_p1);
                int in = get_input("Player 1: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(removed));
                curr_p1 = p1_team[in - 1];

                removed = temp_remove(p2_team, curr_p2);
                in = get_input("Player 2: Which Pokemon Do You Want To Switch Out To?", false, to_string_array(removed));
                curr_p2 = p2_team[in - 1];
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}

////////////////Helper Functions///////////////////

int get_input(const std::string& prompt, bool fast, const std::vector<std::string>& options) {
    if (options.size() == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    print(prompt + " If you want to exit, type -2.");
    for (int i = 0, option_count = 1; i < options.size(); i++, option_count++) {
        print(std::to_string(option_count) + ": " + options[i], fast ? 10 : 50);
    }
    while (true) {
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        if (!is_valid(input, options.size())) {
            print("INVALID");
        } else {
            int num = std::stoi(input);

            if(num == -2) {
                throw std::exception();
            } else {
                return std::stoi(input);
            }
        }
    }
}

void print(const std::string& text, int delay) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << text[i];
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void read_file() {
    std::ifstream data("pokemon_data.txt");
    std::string next_line;
    std::string prev;
    int count = 1;

    while (std::getline(data, next_line)) {
        if (next_line[0] == '#') {
            std::string p_name = split(next_line, 1);
            pokemon_data[p_name] = next_line;;
            available_pokemon[count++] = p_name;
            prev = p_name;
            continue;
        }

        pokemon_moves[prev].push_back(next_line);
    }

    data.close();

    std::ifstream u_pokemon_file("user_pokemon.txt");

    while (std::getline(u_pokemon_file, next_line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> u_pokemon_data;
        prev = next_line;

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            std::getline(u_pokemon_file, next_line);
            u_pokemon_data.push_back(next_line);
        }

        u_pokemon[prev] = u_pokemon_data;
    }

    u_pokemon_file.close();

    std::ifstream u_teams_file("user_teams.txt");

    while (std::getline(u_teams_file, next_line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> team_data;
        prev = next_line;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            std::getline(u_teams_file, next_line);
            team_data.push_back(next_line);
        }

        u_teams[prev] = team_data;
    }

    std::ifstream move_file("move_data.txt");

    while (std::getline(move_file, next_line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> curr_move_data;
        prev = next_line;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            std::getline(move_file, next_line);
            curr_move_data.push_back(next_line);
        }

        move_data[prev] = curr_move_data;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::vector<T>& vector) {
    for (T t : vector) {
        std::cout << t;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string& string) {
    std::vector<std::string> ans;
    std::stringstream stream(string);
    std::string next_line;

    while (std::getline(stream, next_line, ' ')) {
        ans.push_back(next_line);
    }

    return ans;
}

std::string split(std::string& string, int index) {
    return split(string)[index];
}

template<typename K, typename V>
std::vector<std::pair<K, V>> key_value_pairs(std::unordered_map<K, V>& map) {
    std::vector<std::pair<K, V>> ans;

    for (auto& x : map) {
        ans.push_back(std::make_pair(x.first, x.second));
    }

    return ans;
}

void add_user_pokemon(std::string& p_name) {
    std::vector<std::string> u_moves = get_user_moves(p_name);
    print("What Do You Want To Name Your Pokemon? Name Must Be Unique");
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::ofstream file("user_pokemon.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    std::vector<std::string> data = split(pokemon_data[p_name]);
    file << name << "\n" <<
        p_name << "\n" <<
        u_moves[0] << "\n" <<
        u_moves[1] << "\n" <<
        u_moves[2] << "\n" <<
        u_moves[3] << "\n" <<
        data[2] << "\n" <<
        data[3] << "\n" <<
        data[4] << "\n" <<
        data[5] << "\n" <<
        data[6] << "\n" <<
        data[7] << "\n" <<
        data[8] << "\n" <<
        data[9] << "\n";
    file.close();
    u_pokemon[name] = {
        p_name,
        u_moves[0],
        u_moves[1],
        u_moves[2],
        u_moves[3],
        data[2],
        data[3],
        data[4],
        data[5],
        data[6],
        data[7],
        data[8],
        data[9]
    };
}

std::vector<std::string> get_user_moves(std::string& p_name) {
    std::vector<std::string> available_moves = pokemon_moves[p_name];
    std::vector<std::string> u_moves;
    int move_count = 5;
    while (move_count-- > 1) {
        int in = get_input("Choose " + std::to_string(move_count) + " Moves", true, available_moves);
        u_moves.push_back(available_moves[in - 1]);
        available_moves.erase(available_moves.begin() + in - 1);
    }

    return u_moves;
}

void add_team_to_file(std::string& team_name, std::vector<std::string>& p_names) {
    std::ofstream team_file("user_teams.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    team_file << team_name << "\n" <<
        p_names[0] << "\n" <<
        p_names[1] << "\n" <<
        p_names[2] << "\n" <<
        p_names[3] << "\n" <<
        p_names[4] << "\n" <<
        p_names[5] << "\n";
    team_file.close();
}

template<typename T>
void remove(std::vector<T>& vec, T& element) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (vec[i] == element) {
            vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> to_string_array(const std::vector<pokemon>& vec) {
    std::vector<std::string> ans;

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        ans.push_back(vec[i].nick);
    }

    return ans;
}

std::string choose_move(pokemon& p, int player_num) {
    std::string move;

    switch (get_input("Player " + std::to_string(player_num)  + ": Which Move Do You Want To Use?", false,
        {
            p.move1,
            p.move2,
            p.move3,
            p.move4
        }
    )) {
    case MOVE_1:
        move = p.move1;
        break;
    case MOVE_2:
        move = p.move2;
        break;
    case MOVE_3:
        move = p.move3;
        break;
    case MOVE_4:
        move = p.move4;
        break;
    }

    return move;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> temp_remove(std::vector<T> vec, T& to_remove) {
    remove(vec, to_remove);
    return vec;
}

bool is_valid(const std::string& to_check, int max_num) {
    try {
        int num = std::stoi(to_check);
        return num == -2 || (num >= 1 && num <= max_num);
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In a file called `pokemon.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "helper_maps.hpp"
#include "helper_functions.hpp"

namespace p_util {
    void print(std::string text) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            std::cout << text[i];
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> split(std::string string) {
        std::vector<std::string> ans;
        std::stringstream stream(string);
        std::string next_line;

        while (std::getline(stream, next_line, ' ')) {
            ans.push_back(next_line);
        }

        return ans;
    }
}

class pokemon {
private:
    int b_hp, b_attack, b_defense, b_special_attack, b_special_defense, b_speed;
    float type_effectivenss[18][18]{
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {2, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 0.5, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 2, 0.5},
        {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 2, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2},
        {1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0.5, 2, 1, 0.5, 1, 2, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0.5},
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0.5, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 2, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1},
        {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 2, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0},
        {1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5},
        {1, 2, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}
    };
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> type_indices{
        {"normal", 0},
        {"fighting", 1},
        {"flying", 2},
        {"poison", 3},
        {"ground", 4},
        {"rock", 5},
        {"bug", 6},
        {"ghost", 7},
        {"steel", 8},
        {"fire", 9},
        {"water", 10},
        {"grass", 11},
        {"electric", 12},
        {"psychic", 13},
        {"ice", 14},
        {"dragon", 15},
        {"dark", 16},
        {"fairy", 17}
    };
public:
    int s_attack, s_defense, s_special_attack, s_special_defense, s_speed;
    float max_hp, s_hp;
    std::string name, type1, type2, move1, move2, move3, move4, nick;
public:
    pokemon(std::string& _name, std::string& _nick, std::string& _move1, std::string& _move2, std::string& _move3, std::string& _move4) {
        name = _name;
        nick = _nick;
        std::vector<std::string> data = p_util::split(pokemon_data[_name]);
        type1 = data[2];
        type2 = data[3];
        b_hp = std::stoi(data[4]);
        b_attack = std::stoi(data[5]);
        b_defense = std::stoi(data[6]);
        b_special_attack = std::stoi(data[7]);
        b_special_defense = std::stoi(data[8]);
        b_speed = std::stoi(data[9]);
        s_hp = (2 * b_hp) + 110;
        max_hp = s_hp;
        s_attack = b_attack * 2 + 5;
        s_defense = b_defense * 2 + 5;
        s_special_attack = b_special_attack * 2 + 5;
        s_special_defense = b_special_defense * 2 + 5;
        s_speed = b_speed * 2 + 5;
        move1 = _move1;
        move2 = _move2;
        move3 = _move3;
        move4 = _move4;
    }
public:
    bool take_damage(float damage) {
        s_hp -= damage;
        return s_hp <= 0;
    }
    bool attack(std::string& move, pokemon& other, int player_num) {
        std::vector<std::string> data = move_data[move];
        float f_rand = ((rand() % 15) + 85.0) / 100.0;
        float STAB = (data[1] == type1 || data[1] == type2) ? 1.5 : 1;
        float type = type_effectivenss[type_indices[move]][type_indices[other.type1]] *
            type_effectivenss[type_indices[move]][type_indices[other.type2]];

        const float MODIFIER = f_rand * STAB * type;
        const float POWER = std::stoi(data[2]);
        const float ATTACK = data[1] == "p" ? s_attack : s_special_attack;
        const float DEFENSE = data[1] == "p" ? other.s_defense : other.s_special_defense;
        const float DAMAGE = ((52 * POWER * (ATTACK / DEFENSE) / 50) + 2) * MODIFIER;

        bool fainted = other.take_damage(DAMAGE);
        p_util::print("Player " + std::to_string(player_num) + "'s " + other.nick + " Has " + std::to_string((other.s_hp / other.max_hp) * 100) + "% Of It's HP Left");
        return fainted;
    }
    bool operator==(const pokemon& other) const {
        return (name == other.name) &&
            (move1 == other.move1) &&
            (move2 == other.move2) &&
            (move3 == other.move3) &&
            (move4 == other.move4);
    }
};
```

In a file called `helper_functions.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "pokemon.hpp"

int get_input(const std::string& prompt, bool fast, const std::vector<std::string>& options);

void print(const std::string& text, int delay = 50);

void read_file();

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string& string);

std::string split(std::string& string, int index);

template <typename K, typename V>
std::vector<std::pair<K, V>> key_value_pairs(std::unordered_map<K, V>& map);

template <typename T>
void print_vector(std::vector<T>& vector);

void add_user_pokemon(std::string& p_name);

std::vector<std::string> get_user_moves(std::string& p_name);

void add_team_to_file(std::string& team_name, std::vector<std::string>& p_names);

template <typename T>
void remove(std::vector<T>& vec, T& element);

std::vector<std::string> to_string_array(const std::vector<pokemon>& vec);

std::string choose_move(pokemon& p, int player_num);

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> temp_remove(std::vector<T> vec, T& to_remove);

bool is_valid(const std::string& to_check, int max_num);
```

And finally, in a file called `gameplay_functions.hpp`:

````
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "pokemon.hpp"

void start();
void create_team();
void battle();
void create_pokemon();
void add_pokemon(std::vector<std::string>& u_team);
void battle(std::vector<pokemon>& p1_team, std::vector<pokemon>& p2_team,
    pokemon& p1_lead, pokemon& p2_lead);
```
````

Comment: You are asking us to review the visual appeal of your game, is there any chance you could add some example output?